# Flutter riverpod debounce multiple dependent providers

Tags: flutter, riverpod

As described in the Riverpod docs, a Riverpod provider can watch other providers to make a "processing pipeline".

I have something like this:

```
final prov = Provider<String>((ref){

    final w1 = ref.watch(prov1);
    final w2 = ref.watch(prov2);
    final w3 = ref.watch(prov3);
    final w4 = ref.watch(prov4);

    final complex = expensiveFunction(w1,w2,w3,w4);

    return complex;
});
```

`prov1` to `prov4` can be modified individually by various bits of UI
But some UI actions cause some or all of them to change in quick succession.

How can I debounce calls to `expensiveFunction()` until none of `w1`..`w4` have changed for say 2 secs?

Comment: Did you get any luck with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this tweet](https://twitter.com/remi_rousselet/status/1493523352543285250) of the author of the riverpod package, here is how you can do it:

```dart
/// An extension on [Ref] with helpful methods to add a debounce.
extension RefDebounceExtension on Ref {
  /// Delays an execution by a bit such that if a dependency changes multiple
  /// time rapidly, the rest of the code is only run once.
  Future<void> debounce(Duration duration) {
    final completer = Completer<void>();
    final timer = Timer(duration, () {
      if (!completer.isCompleted) completer.complete();
    });
    onDispose(() {
      timer.cancel();
      if (!completer.isCompleted) {
        completer.completeError(StateError('Cancelled'));
      }
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
}

final prov = FutureProvider<String>((ref) async {

    final w1 = ref.watch(prov1);
    final w2 = ref.watch(prov2);
    final w3 = ref.watch(prov3);
    final w4 = ref.watch(prov4);

    await debounce(Duration(seconds: 2));

    final complex = expensiveFunction(w1,w2,w3,w4);

    return complex;
});
```

Comment: If I have understood correctly, _expensiveFunction_ will not work because of _throwing error_. Is my understanding true?